# Existing controller adding views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

New to RoR.

I created a controller

```
rails generate controller Dave teach speak dig
```

That created my controller Dave and also the 3 views. It did all the backend stuff too like adding the route and adding the 3 methods under application.html.erb and finally the correct routes.

Now I want to add more views. Do I have to go and manually type it out to the application.html.erb and then add a new line to routes.rb and finally manually create a new view? (3 steps)

Or is there a line of code that does all that for me like the original line

Comment: What do you type in `application.html.haml`? You mean links to these view? And the answer is: you have to add it manually, there's no rails generator for adding new actions/views.

Comment: learn about `scaffolding`

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend to read the guides at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/

In your case http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html would help you...